# Weird behaviour of request-json with bluebird promise

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to wrap my head around promises, but so far I can't seem to get simple example working. Here it a code to request JSON from the server:

```
module.exports = function (app, options) {
var promise = require('bluebird');
var request = require('request-json');

var module = {
    url: options.url,
    httpClient: promise.promisifyAll(request.createClient(options.url))
};

module.getSample = function() {
    return this.httpClient.getAsync('sample/')
        .then(function(error, response, body) {
            console.log(body);
        })
        .catch(function(e) {
            console.log('error');
            console.log(e);
        });
};

return module;
```

};

but when I call it like this:

```
var backendClient = require('./utils/backendClient.js')(app, {
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/'
});

backendClient.getSample()
```

at runtime I get an error saying '[SyntaxError: Unexpected token o]'. Version without promises works fine. What did I miss?

Comment: Where do you get the syntax error, in what line of which file?

Comment: I'm used to seeing `Unexpected token o` from JSON.parse -- are you sure you're getting a JSON? Also a promise can only be resolved with one value, so your `error, response, body` signature is incorrect, simplest way to see what's going on is to `console.log(arguments)` and see what the resolved object is

Comment: @Madd0g yep, code works fine without promises. about the signature - that's what I missed. will try again tomorrow. thanks

Comment: @chester89: If it's a runtime error, please post the complete stack trace.

Comment: @chester89: Also you might want to show us the working (non-promise) code so that we can identify what is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module.getSample = function() {
    return this.httpClient.getAsync('sample/')
        .then(function(error, response, body) {
            // not sure what Promise library you are using, but in the Promise/A+ spec, the function in then only receives a single argument, the resolved value of the Promise
            console.log(body);
            // this returns equivalent to Promise.resolve(undefined);
            // you really want to return something meaningful here
        })
        .catch(function(e) {
            console.log('error');
            console.log(e);
            // this also returns equivalent to Promise.resolve(undefined);
            // to propagate the "error" condition, you want to either throw e, or return Promise.reject(something here);
        });
};
```

This will always return a fullfilled promise with *undefined* as the value, never a rejected one. Other errors commented above

Comment: thanks, it all worked out - I used spread instead of then and added return statement